# How to print the "|" symbol in C++

Tags: c++

I need to print out the "|" symbol on the screen. But I seem to get this instead of correct symbol:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <=8; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)cout << " ";
        else cout << i; 
        cout << "\|";
    }
```

How do I do it? Sorry if this is a stupid question...

Comment: How the `|` looks depends on your terminal and it's settings, so it is printing correctly.

Comment: Isn't that how | looks on a windows terminal?

Comment: Maybe edit the windows console program to do it. :)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour how to change the settings?

Comment: How to change the terminal font in Windows can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/5035/how-to-change-the-windows-xp-console-font

Comment: Maybe you're looking for character 179 from extended ASCII. Try `cout << char(179);`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar

Comment: The vertical bar doesn't need to be escaped. This is not GREP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is how your console displays the `|` character.  You could change your console font if this is a problem.

Alternatively you could use the extended ASCII character with value `179` in decimal. That looks like `│` and I'm sure you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

In your font, that little double-vertical bar *is* the `|` symbol.
If you don't like it, change the font.

Answer (score 1):

Console -> Properties.
Navigate to "Font" tab and change the Font e.g. "Consolas"
It will display pipe symbol as |